# How to open link on new window on Ipad

Tags: javascript, ipad

I have a site which is running on Asp.net and on front-end I am using JavaScript for UI functionality. I am using window.open() function of JavaScript and its working fine on web browsers. But when I am testing this site on my I pad then this link is opening on new tab instead of new window.
I have spent several hours to fix this issue Please suggest.Immediate response will be Appreciated.

I have got the same as my problem in this question [On clild window close cannot send value to parent window in JavaScript for iPad Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10535439/on-clild-window-close-cannot-send-value-to-parent-window-in-javascript-for-ipad) but unfortunately this question has no answer.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZM60LyxQufg

Answer (score 1):

It is the property of browser, if the browser wants to open the link in a new tab or in a window.

Comment: so should i have to do setting of the browser in Ipad?

Comment: I guess safari has only tabs, It is highly browser dependent thing, And browser will not allow you to modify its functionality this way.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response but i am not using safari ,I am using chrome on my ipad.Please let me know the setting of chrome for opening link on new window

Comment: A new window means a new instance of the particular browser.. More RAM consumption.. IPAD and even browser will not simply allow you that.

Answer (score 1):

the safari on iPad you mean? no, it only has tabs. even though there's a separate window for private mode, which groups all private tabs under it.

But strictly speaking, no, there isn't a function for that. And same goes with most, if not all, other 3rd party browsers on iOS.

Comment: If there is any setting exist then please let me know about the browser setting?

Comment: If by setting you mean for the window settings, unfortunately, there isn't one. The mobile safari is meant to be simplified, and the traditional desktop's windowed environment directly contradicts ios' design. And even if there were windows, those windows would be for all applications that are laid out on a "desktop" space, which is also non existent in ios. I suggest that you find a workaround or simply use "new tabs" if it works for you